# Error building expo react-native app with npx eas build ios

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, expo

On android, the app builds OK, but when i am trying to build it with ios the "install pods" fails: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikkf.png)

Here is the errormessage

[!] The following Swift pods cannot yet be integrated as static libraries:

The Swift pod `FirebaseCoreInternal` depends upon `GoogleUtilities`, which does not define modules. To opt into those targets generating module maps (which is necessary to import them from Swift when building as static libraries), you may set `use_modular_headers!` globally in your Podfile, or specify `:modular_headers => true` for particular dependencies.

Note:

- i am not using XCode, but expo...

i have tried to create ios/Podfile and added some
"pod 'SomePod', :modular_headers => true" for each of the failing pods.
I have tried deleting package.lock and node_modules and reinstalled it.

Comment: Please check this seems like the same issue:
https://www.reddit.com/r/expo/comments/wsmhrs/getting_error_when_building_ios_app_by_using_eas/